# Editing values in DataFrafe column -Python & PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert all values < 100 to 0 in column ODOMETER_FW. I have below DF:

[image]

When I use pandas:

```
stupid_values = fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW'].replace(fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW']<100,0)
fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW'] = stupid_values
fuel_GB.head(13)
```

And the result as you can see, has some error and I really do not know why.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lambda` function to convert values less than 100 to 0:

```
df['ODOMETER_FW'] = df['ODOMETER_FW'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <100 else x)
print(df)
   ODOMETER_FW
0         11833
1             0
2          9080
3          8878
4             0
5         14578
6         14351
7             0
8         13456
9             0
10            0
11            0
12            0
```

Comment: Why use `apply()` and a lambda instead of simply `fuel_GB[fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW'] < 100, 'ODOMETER_FW'] = 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask the modification for the relevant lines:

```
fuel_GB.loc[fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW'] < 100, 'ODOMETER_FW'] = 0
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunatelly it is not working: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: @Ventre90: Shame on me, I forgot the `.loc`. Fixed...

Comment: @ Serge Ballesta, It also works great. Thank You for your dedication!

Answer (score 0):

Use this pandas code:

```py
fuel_GB[fuel_GB['ODOMETER_FW'] < 100] = 0
```

Comment: Hi it is changing all values in mentioned rows on 0. I need 0 only in ODOMETER_FW column when start value is < 100. But thank you for help.